# JSF - como enviar informação para outra pagina

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tenho um `orderList` para o operador selecionar o nome do cliente. Após ele selecionar preciso direcionar ele para outra pagina com os dados do cliente. Como faço para passar as informações do cliente que foi selecionado para outra pagina xhtml? Qual é o raciocínio para fazer isso?

Comment: O racioncínio é: a página que deve mostrar os dados do cliente espera um parâmetro com o ID do cliente, e a página onde o cliente é selecionado (seu orderList) renderiza, para cada cliente, um link para a página de detalhes, passando neste link o ID do cliente. Captou?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar os parameters:

No XHTML

```
<p:commandButton title="EDITAR" action="/pagina?faces-redirect=true">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{flash.objeto}"
    value="#{listItem}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

No ManagedBean    `(Objeto)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().get("objeto")`

Dessa forma o id não sera passado via url, sendo assim se seu cliente recarregar a pagina a mesma vira sem os dados.